# CakePHP should I be using keepExisting in a HABTM relationship?

Tags: cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many

I'm new to Cake, and trying to figure out how this is possible or if I'm going about it the wrong way.

```
Question hasMany Answer
Quiz HABTM Answer
```

So I have the following tables: quizzes, answers, quizzes_answers

However, there's one type of question that doesn't fit the mold.  This type of question needs to record an image_id.  So I was thinking of storing this data in the association table, but I'm not sure how to use the HABTM setting:

```
'unique' => 'keepExisting'
```

It doesn't seem like this will work to save the data I need.  And if so, how would I structure the form in the view to save this data?

---

Or... should I be creating another Model?  If I cannot successfully save an image_id in the associated table, maybe the alternative is to have another association with the Quiz model and a new model?

```
Quiz hasMany StudentAnswer
```

Where I'd store the quiz_id, question_id, answer_id, and image_id.  The last one: image_id would be 0 unless the question being asked is of a specific type.  In this situation I would remove the HABTM association above.

Hopefully this is clear.  I can elaborate further if necessary.

Update:
I'm able to save quiz_id, answer_id, and image_id for the quizzes_answers table.  However, if more updates are made the prior associations are deleted.  And I have unique set to keepExisting in the models.

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array( // Quiz Model
    'Answer' => array(
        'className' => 'Answer',
        'joinTable' => 'quizzes_answers',
        'foreignKey' => 'quiz_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'answer_id',
        'unique' => 'keepExisting',
        'dependent' => true,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'deleteQuery' => '',
        'insertQuery' => ''
    )

public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array( // Answer Model
    'Quiz' => array(
        'className' => 'Quiz',
        'joinTable' => 'quizzes_answers',
        'foreignKey' => 'answer_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'quiz_id',
        'unique' => 'keepExisting',
        'dependent' => true,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'deleteQuery' => '',
        'insertQuery' => ''
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

### There is no HABTM in the question

In the question it's described that there is:

```
Quiz hasAndBelongsToMany Answer
```

i.e. there is a table like this:

```
answers_quizes
    answer_id
    quiz_id
```

What about *who* answered the question? Unless there is only one student ever taking a given quiz - a habtm association is inappropriate.

### Create a model for the join table

*especially in light of previous point*

Here's a simple rule, which makes some schema/code decisions easy:

> A join table with more than 2 fields is not a join table. It is a model in its own right and needs a primary key.

That doesn't mean you can't use habtm - it just means the choice is there for when to do so (reading data perhaps) and when not (saving).

### keepExisting?

[Keep existing](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasandbelongstomany-habtm) means:

> When [unique is set to] keepExisting, the behavior is similar to true, but existing associations are not deleted.

That is, if there is existing habtm data for a given user and question, it will not be deleted before inserting the new records. That would be appropriate if for example the one user was allowed to answer the same question multiple times and you want to store all attempts, instead of just the last one.

Comment: I was only referring to the tables in question.  There is a user_id in the quiz.  User hasMany Quiz.  The reason Quizzes/Answers is HABTM is that the answer is already there.  I'm just linking the answer the user chose to the question. E.g. multiple choice, 4 existing answers. quizzes_answers stores the answer that the user chose for the quiz.  The quiz has all the associations to the questions-- Quiz HABTM Question.  Is this bad?

Comment: If it fits the purpose no. I can't visualize how storing quiz<->answer records helps - unless there is only one question in each "quiz" - does quiz really mean question?.

Comment: A quiz consists of 3 different types of questions: multiple choice, true false, and image matching.  Multiple choice has only 1 correct answer, true false has 0-4 True answers.  Matching consists of a set of 5 images and 5 questions.  Each question must be matched with an image.  Quiz<->answer record helps because it indicates what was chosen by the user for that specific, dynamically created quiz.